# C++ SFML Image loading fails on iter

Tags: c++, sfml, stdmap

I'm new to C++, in order to learn it better (I learn from doing) I have rewritten the code from an example C++ game I found over on GitHub, I intend to alter pieces of code to expand on it and change the graphics once I have it working in order to know exactly what does what. Rather than simply copying and pasting the existing code I made sure to write it all myself, I believe re-writing code gives a better understanding than simply copy&paste.

I'm trying to load images for a small game as a C++ test, when trying to execute the code from the IDE it keeps failing near `if(iter == _images.end())` I have tried everything I myself can think of like changing the type of _images, changing how `filename` gets made, adding checks, removing checks, I have spent the last 3 days on Google and StackOverflow trying every fix I came accross that mentioned a similar problem. So far nothing has helped.

I will post the code sections I believe relevant to this here, please have a look and point me to where or how to fix this.

First things first, the error it shows me:

```
Exception thrown: read access violation.
std::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >,sf::Texture,std::less<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > >,std::allocator<std::pair<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > const ,sf::Texture> >,0> >::_Root(...) returned 0x4.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.
```

From what I have gathered this has to do with the memory it is trying to read/write to.

Call Stack

```
FileName.exe!std::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >,sf::Texture,std::less<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > >,std::allocator<std::pair<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > const ,sf::Texture> >,0> >::_Lbound<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > >(const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > & _Keyval) Line 2060    C++
FileName.exe!std::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >,sf::Texture,std::less<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > >,std::allocator<std::pair<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > const ,sf::Texture> >,0> >::lower_bound(const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > & _Keyval) Line 1538   C++
FileName.exe!std::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >,sf::Texture,std::less<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > >,std::allocator<std::pair<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > const ,sf::Texture> >,0> >::find(const std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > & _Keyval) Line 1481  C++
FileName.exe!VisibleGameObject::Load(std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > filename) Line 17 C++
FileName.exe!Player::Player() Line 7    C++
FileName.exe!`dynamic initializer for 'speler''() Line 30   C++
[External Code]
```

VisibleGameObject.cpp

```
void VisibleGameObject::Load(std::string filename) {
    filename = "textures/" + filename;

    //Basic algorithm for images
    auto iter = _images.find(filename);
    if (iter == _images.end()) {
        sf::Texture texture;
        if (!texture.loadFromFile(filename)) {
            std::cout << "[ERROR] Image failed to load!" << std::endl;
            assert(false);
        }
        auto img = _images.insert(std::pair<std::string, sf::Texture>(filename, texture)).first;
        std::cout << "[DEBUG] " + filename + ": Loaded and added to cache." << std::endl;
        _sprite.setTexture(img->second);
        _isLoaded = true;
    }
    else {
        _sprite.setTexture(iter->second);
        _isLoaded = true;
    }
    _imageKey = filename;
}
```

VisibleGameObject.h

```
#pragma once
#include "stdafx.h"

class VisibleGameObject {
public:
    VisibleGameObject();
    virtual ~VisibleGameObject();

    virtual void Load(std::string filename);
    virtual void Draw(sf::RenderWindow & window);
    virtual void Update(float elapsedTime) = 0;

    virtual void SetPosition(float x, float y);
    virtual sf::Vector2f GetPosition() const;
    virtual float GetWidth() const;
    virtual float GetHeight() const;

    virtual sf::Rect<float> GetBoundingRect() const;
    virtual bool IsLoaded() const;

    virtual bool ShouldPersist() const;
    virtual void ToggleVisibility(bool isVisible);
    virtual bool ShouldDraw() const;

protected:
    sf::Sprite& GetSprite();

private:
    sf::Sprite _sprite;
    std::string _imageKey;
    bool _isLoaded;
    bool _shouldDraw;
    static std::map<std::string, sf::Texture> _images;
};
```

stdafx.h

```
#pragma once

#include "targetver.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

#include <SFML/System.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>

#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
```

The call to VisibleGameObject.cpp happens from Game.cpp

```
void Game::Start() {
    _mainWindow.create(sf::VideoMode(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT), "Window PlaceHolder Title");

    Background *background1 = new Background(1);
    background1->SetPosition(0.f, -768.f);
    _gameObjectManager.Add("bg1", background1);

    Background *background2 = new Background(2);
    background2->SetPosition(0.f, -768.f);
    _gameObjectManager.Add("bg2", background2);

    Background *background4 = new Background(4);
    background4->SetPosition(0.f, -768.f);
    _gameObjectManager.Add("bg4", background4);

    Player *player = new Player();
    player->ResetStartingPosition();
    _gameObjectManager.Add("player", player);

    MainHUD *hud = new MainHUD();
    _gameObjectManager.Add("hud", hud);

    GameOverHUD *gameOver = new GameOverHUD();
    _gameObjectManager.Add("gameover", gameOver);

    while (!IsExiting()) {
        GameLoop();
    }

    _mainWindow.close();
}
```

If anything is missing or I have added things that can be exluded, let me know and I will edit the question.

Comment: Which image fails? The first? The last? Any one seemingly random? Can you cut it down to a [mcve]?

Comment: From what I can tell it only happens on the player image, I will rewrite it in a new solution with just the stuff for the player and test it again to make sure.

Comment: @DevelopmentSideShowMedia Not sure if you fixed this or not, however I am not seeing visibleObject::load being called anywhere in the code you provided... Nor do I have an idea what your background or player are...  The callstack says its calling into visibleobject from your player.cpp could you show us where you are calling load from your player.cpp?  Can you also show us where you define _images, I see where you declared it.

Comment: Sorry for the slow response, haven't had the time over the weekend, I have fixed the issue I had, I dont recall how I did it, it sort of happened while I was trying bits and pieces of code, moving things around, etc. Currently I am struggling with displaying the animation of a GIF, but that is unrelated to this since the image actually loads. Thank you all for the help provided, if wanted I can sniff through my code and grab the fixed version and put it in the question for others.